# Compiling Junit on windows 8 command line error

Tags: java, command-line, junit, javac

I created a Junit test case using Eclipse and it works fine. I am trying to compile it using command line but can't seem to do it.

I was able to "compile" it fine..but now when I try to run it I get the following error:

```
 JUnit version 4.8.2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDesc
ribing
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.junit.runner.Computer.getSuite(Computer.java:26)
        at org.junit.runner.Request.classes(Request.java:69)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:117)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:98)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMainAndExit(JUnitCore.java:53)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:45)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 18 more
```

To run it I am using:

```
java -cp "E:/Android ADT/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219/eclipse/plugins/org.junit_4.8.2.v4_8_2_v20110321-1705/junit.jar;." org.junit.runner.JUnitCore SchedulerTest
```

The compilation worked fine, and for compiling I used:

```
javac -cp "E:/Android ADT/adt-bundle-windows
-x86_64-20130219/eclipse/plugins/org.junit_4.8.2.v4_8_2_v20110321-1705/junit.jar
;." SchedulerTest.java
```

Comment: Do you use the hamcrest bundled inside the `junit.jar` or do you have a separate dependency?

Comment: Don't believe so. The only thing I am importing is :
 
`import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;`

Answer (score 0):

When compilation works fine but you get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` when running the code, that usually indicates a missing runtime dependency. As in this case, `org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing` is not used at compile time, but required at runtime.

`hamcrest` is usually bundled within the official `junit.jar` that you can download from junit.org, however your `E:/Android ADT/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219/eclipse/plugins/org.junit_4.8.2.v4_8_2_v20110321-1705/junit.jar` doesn't have it. Look for a hamcrest jar in the Android ADT plugins directory `E:/Android ADT/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219/eclipse/plugins/` and include that in your classpath when you run your application.

That is, run like this:

```
java -cp "E:/Android ADT/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219/eclipse/plugins/PATH_TO_HAMCREST.jar;E:/Android ADT/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219/eclipse/plugins/org.junit_4.8.2.v4_8_2_v20110321-1705/junit.jar;." org.junit.runner.JUnitCore SchedulerTest
```

Finally, the unit test works fine in Eclipse because there hamcrest is part of the default classpath when you run unit tests.